# C++ round a double up to 2 decimal places

Tags: c++, rounding, cin, ceil

I am having trouble rounding a GPA double to 2 decimal places. (ex of a GPA needed to be rounded: 3.67924) I am currently using ceil to round up, but it currently outputs it as a whole number (368)

here is what I have right now

```
if (cin >> gpa) {
    if (gpa >= 0 && gpa <= 5) {
           // valid number

           gpa = ceil(gpa * 100);

           break;
    } else {
           cout << "Please enter a valid GPA (0.00 - 5.00)" << endl;
           cout << "GPA: ";

    }
}
```

using the above code with 3.67924 would output 368 (which is what I want, but just without the period between the whole number and the decimals). How can I fix this?

Comment: After you multiplied by 100 and rounded, divide back by 100. Or, if all you need is to **print** with two decimal places, keep the value unchanged and use [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) when printing.

Comment: The title mentions rounding up, but the problem statement mentions rounding. Rounding could be implemented with gpa = floor((100.*gpa)+.5)/100.

Comment: `would output 368 (which is what I want, but just without the period between the whole number and the decimals). How can I fix this?` you would do this `gpa /= 100` assuming `gpa` is a `double`.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 51):

To round a double up to 2 decimal places, you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    double value = 0.123;
    value = std::ceil(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
    std::cout << value << std::endl; // prints 0.13
    return 0;
}
```

To round up to n decimal places, you can use:

```
double round_up(double value, int decimal_places) {
    const double multiplier = std::pow(10.0, decimal_places);
    return std::ceil(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

This method won't be particularly fast, if performance becomes an issue you may need another solution.

Comment: In my specific case I preferred to use `std::round` instead of `std::ceil`, but your solution was absolutely perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

If it is just a matter of writing to screen then to round the number use

```
std::cout.precision(3);
std::cout << gpa << std::endl;
```

[see](https://ideone.com/w4PsI5)

floating points are not exactly represented so by internally rounding the value and then using that in your calculations you are increasing the inexactness.

Answer (score 6):

You can't round doubles to two decimal places. Doubles don't *have* decimal places. They have binary places, and they aren't commensurable with decimal places.

If you want decimal places, you must use a decimal radix, e.g. when formatting for output with printf("%.2f", ...).

Comment: True, but not necessarily helpful - it's still common enough to want the *nearest* `double` to the intended 2-decimal-digit number, for example - as a step before doing some other calculation to minimise further errors.

Comment: @TonyD He says he wants `3.68`. Nothing about the 'nearest'.

Comment: @TonyDelroy And premature rounding will *cause* further errors.

Comment: When you narrow the scenarios to those characterised as "premature", sure - the word implies an error.  But other times _earlier_ rounding is the best way to use doubles to calculate something and shouldn't be termed "premature".  E.g. if a contract said a discount applied on a per-item basis, rounded up, then that should be done before multiplication by the quantity of items involved.  There *can* be value in having the closest possible double representation to a specific two-decimal-place-value, even when you know it's not that exact thing.  Incidentally, it may be exact - e.g. 0.25, 0.75.

Comment: @TonyDelroy There can be what value? The time to do the rounding is at the end when you arrive at the decimal radix.

Comment: I already gave you an example of when it may have value above - rounding item prices before multiplying by quantity, if the business logic is that it should work that way.  For example, it might be item price * 0.9 (for 10% discount), rounded, then multiplied by qty, then round that again.  You could of course do the pricing using integers for greater assurances, but if you're using doubles (as many systems do), then it may well be that rounding at all the right times prevents errors at any given stage compounding to change the overall result.

Comment: This answer is the right one actually.  The result is simply wrong in some cases if you use binary floating point number, like round(0.575, 2) won't be correct using any of the other answers.  You just have to use decimal numbers to get the right answer.

Comment: @TonyDelroy The fewer times you round, the smaller will be the rounding errors. There are no two ways about this.

Comment: Doubles _may_ have decimal places - you can find out whether they do on your target by testing the macro `FLT_RADIX`.

Answer (score 5):

When you are trying to store values upto n decimal values in a variable .
You have to multiple that value with 10^n and divide the same with 10^n.
Afterward use type operator to manipulate in the program.
Here is the example : -

```
 float a,b,c,d,sum;

 cin>>a>>b>>c>>d; // reading decimal values

sum=(a*b*c*d);

sum=round(sum*100)/100; // here it is for 2 decimal points

if((float)sum < (float) 9.58)
  cout<<"YES\n";
else
  cout<<"NO\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. But your `cout` statement in else condition, so it won't give the desired output for 3.67924.

```
if (cin >> gpa)
{     
    if (gpa >= 0 && gpa <= 5) {
        // valid number

        gpa = ceil(gpa * 100);
        gpa=gpa/100;
        break;
    } 
    else
    {    
       cout << "Please enter a valid GPA (0.00 - 5.00)" << endl;    
       cout << "GPA: ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example: you want 56.899999999999 to be output as a string with 2 decimal point which is 56.89.

> **First, convert them**
>   value = 56.89 * 1000  = 5689
>   factor = 100
>   - 1 decimal point = 10
>   - 2 decimal point = 100
>   - 3 decimal point = 1000
>   etc

```
int integerValue;
int decimal;
std::string result;
function ( int value , int factor)
{
    integerValue= (value / factor) * factor; //(5689 / 100) * 100 = 5600
    decimal = value - integerValue;  // 5689 - 5600;
    result = std::to_string((int)(value/factor) + "." + std::to_string(decimal); 
    // result = "56" + "." + "89" 
    // lastly, print result
}
```

Not sure if this can help?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a combination of fixed and setprecision().

```
 cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
 cout << gpa;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string precision_2(float number)
{
    int decimal_part = (number * 100) - ((int)number * 100);
    if (decimal_part > 10) {
        return std::to_string((int)number) + "." + std::to_string(decimal_part);
    } else {
        return std::to_string((int)number) + ".0" + std::to_string(decimal_part);
    }
}
```

Handles well for all positive floats. A minor modification will make it work for -ves as well.

Comment: This is an old thread which has been answered before by many people. Thanks for contributing to the community, but maybe focus your effort on recently opened unanswered questions.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Rounds a value to n decimal places according to the precision, using the rounding rule of natural numbers
double round_d(double var, int precision=2)
{
    // if precision = 3 then
    // 37.66666 * 10^3 =37666.66
    // 37666.66 + .5 =37667.1    for rounding off value
    // then type cast to <int> so value is 37667
    // then divided by 10^3 so the value converted into 37.667
    if (precision < 0) precision = 0;
    double value = (var >= 0) ? (int)(var * pow(10, precision) + .5) : (int)(var * pow(10, precision) - .5);
    return value / pow(10, precision);
}


int main()
{
    double var1 = 37.66666,
           var2 = 48.7432,
           var3 = 59.8653,
           var4 = -6.305,
           var5 = 1000.296,
           var6 = 500;
    cout << round(var1, 2) << endl <<
            round(var2, 3) << endl <<
            round(var3, 1) << endl <<
            round(var4) << endl <<
            round(var5, 0) << endl <<
            round(var6, 3);

    return 0;
}

// Output:
// 37.67
// 48.743
// 59.9
// -6.31
// 1000
// 500
```

Comment: Any reason to not use `std::round`?

Comment: `std::round` rounds the double or float values to the nearest integer value.
Author asked how to round a double up to 2 (or any number of) decimal places.

Comment: I'm not saying to replace the entire function with `std::round`. Just the part of it where you do `(var >= 0) ? (int)(... + .5) : (int)(... - .5)`.

Comment: Oh, that's it! Well, maybe. What's the difference, why is `std::round` better than cast to `int`? Faster?

Comment: At least it's less typing and expresses the intent better. I'm also sure that `std::round` will always do the right thing, but I'm not sure about your approach. What will happen numbers larger than what's representable by an `int`? Probably nothing good.

Comment: I agree, it's a problem if value is greater than `INT_MAX`. In case of using `std:round` decision is `return std::round(var * pow(10, precision)) / pow(10, precision);` @prashantbade answered correctly. But the answer with high votes is not correct. Solution with `std::ceil` does not round according to the rounding rule of natural numbers, but always downwards.